# Package with "typing" subpackage causing naming collision

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I'm having an issue with a Python package that has a `typing` subpackage. When I try to import a module from this package, it seems that the `typing` subpackage in the package is being assigned to the global namespace of `mypackage`, causing naming collisions with the built-in `typing` module that I import in the `mypackage/__init__.py`.

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to run:

```py
import typing

# MyModule imports typing subpackage of the package
# which leads to naming collision
from mypackage.mysubpackage.mymodule import MyModule

# Some code that uses MyModule and typing

some_var: typing.Final[str] = "string value" # fails here
```

When I run this code, I get an error that says:

```
AttributeError: module 'mypackage.typing' has no attribute 'Final'
```

I've checked the `mypackage` package, and it does indeed have a `typing` subpackage. However, I don't understand why importing `MyModule` would cause the `typing` module in `mypackage` to be assigned to my global namespace.

The problem seems to be happening in the `__init__.py` file of the `mypackage` package. Here's the file structure of the package:

markdown

```markdown
mypackage/
├── __init__.py
├── mysubpackage/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mymodule.py
└── typing/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── myothermodule.py
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: So this is your package, and you are the one editing `__init__.py`? If so, just rename `mypackage.typing` to something else. You shouldn't be naming modules or files after Python built-ins or std. lib modules.

Comment: I wouldn't necessary say the other `typing` needs to be renamed, but it may be a bug if it is exposing the name in a way that shadows the `typing` module in the standard  library. (For example, the other package may not be using relative imports, or it may not be using them correctly.)